# selenium webdriver: I want to click on the next page till last page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time

url = 'https://curecity.in/vendor-list.php?category=Doctor&filters_location=Jaipur&filters%5Bsubareas_global%5D=&filters_speciality='

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()


next_page_number=1
next_page = True
while next_page == True:
     soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
     for link in soup.find_all('div',class_='col-md-9 feature-info'):
        link1 = link.find('a')
        print(link1['href'])
     try:
        driver.find_element_by_link_text(">").click()
        next_page_number+=1
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        print ('No more pages')
        next_page=False

driver.close()
```

i am trying to click on the next page but the code written above is clicking on the alternate pages..I want to click from first page till last page.

Comment: maybe use other method to find button to next page.

Comment: code works for me - I have only `sleep()` longer before `click()`

Answer (score 0):

I found two problems on this page.

1) it loads page very slow so I had to sleep even 10 seconds before get data and `click()` button.

2) button `>` works different then I expect - it jumps 3 pages (even if I click it manually in browser) so I search button with number of next page and click it.

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-page="{}"]'.format(next_page_number)).click()
```

---

Full code. Works even without `BeautifulSoup`

```
from selenium import webdriver
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time

url = 'https://curecity.in/vendor-list.php?category=Doctor&filters_location=Jaipur&filters%5Bsubareas_global%5D=&filters_speciality='

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver.exe')
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get(url)
next_page_number = 1

while True:

    print('page:', next_page_number)
    time.sleep(10)

    #soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    #for link in soup.find_all('div',class_='col-md-9 feature-info'):
    #    link1 = link.find('a')
    #    print(link1['href'])

    for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-md-2 feature-icon"]/a'):
        print(link.get_attribute('href'))

    try:
        next_page_number += 1
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-page="{}"]'.format(next_page_number)).click()
    except:
        print('No more pages')
        break # exit loop

#driver.close()
```